looking for an English skit about an incompetent genealogist
Forty-five to fifty-five years ago I saw an English comedy skit: in it a client arrives at a genealogist’s office to collect his family tree, but after the genealogist has asked one or two minor questions, he suddenly drops to his knees, addressing the client as, “Your Majesty.”
The client is lapping this up, until he sees the paperwork, and points out that the genealogist has written his name down wrongly — I think ‘Smythe’ rather than ‘Smith’ or something like. At that point the genealogist explodes and chases him out of the office.
I thought this was a Monty Python production, and I thought the genealogist was John Cleese, but I’ve never seen it in any list of their work.
Any ideas?

Sounds like Fry and Laurie rather than Monty Python.

Or Absolutely (1989). They used to do those sorts of single-room skits

Was it in colour or black and white? If it was black and white it could be "At Last! The 1948 Show" or "The Frost Report", if colour, it could be "How to Irritate People"? (pre-Monty Python sketch shows starring John Cleese)

I am sure that Fry and Laurie and Absolutely are too early (but at least I have things to look for, so thanks).
The lists of episodes for The Frost Report and How to Irritate People don't sound right.
I think it was black and white, but that's not the sort of thing I remember ...
I'll search through The Marty Feldman Comedy Machine next,

@Barnaby - I saw someone in a forum mention the "Absolutely 'family tree sketch'". I don't know what they're referring to, though.

The complete title appears to be Disastrous family ancestors sketch, so probably not.

FWIW, I'm pretty sure it's not Python, Fry & Laurie, Absolutely, How To Irritate People, or At Last The 1948 Show.  Could it have been in one of the lost episodes of Do Not Adjust Your Set?  (Or The Two Ronnies?)
